# How to use MSAL Python library to create an Azure Activity log

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to use MSAL Python library to create an alert in Azure Activity Log. Here is my code:

```
    from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
MSAL_CLIENT_ID = "<My Client Id>" 
MSAL_CLIENT_SECRET = "<My Client Secret>"
TENANT_ID = "<My Tenant Id>"

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(
    client_id = MSAL_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret = MSAL_CLIENT_SECRET,
    tenant_id = TENANT_ID
)

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "<My Subscription Id>"
monitor_client = MonitorManagementClient(
    credential=credentials,
    subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)

GROUP_NAME = "<My Resource Group Name>"
ACTIVITY_LOG_ALERT_NAME = "test"

log_alert = monitor_client.activity_log_alerts.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    ACTIVITY_LOG_ALERT_NAME,
    {
      "location": "Global",
      "scopes": [
        "subscriptions/" + SUBSCRIPTION_ID
      ],
      "enabled": True,
      "condition": {
        "all_of": [
          {
            "field": "category",
            "equals": "Administrative"
          },
          {
            "field": "level",
            "equals": "Error"
          }
        ]
      },
      "actions": {
        "action_groups": [
        ]
      },
      "description": "Sample activity log alert description"
    }
)
print("Create activity log alert:\n{}".format(log_alert))
```

But I got the following error

HttpResponseError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_24988\3130136741.py in 
----> 1 log_alert = monitor_client.activity_log_alerts.create_or_update(
2     GROUP_NAME,
3     ACTIVITY_LOG_ALERT_NAME,
4     {
5       "location": "Global",

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\hlgdev\lib\site-packages\azure\core\tracing\decorator.py in wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
76             span_impl_type = settings.tracing_implementation()
77             if span_impl_type is None:
---> 78                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
79
80             # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\hlgdev\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\monitor\v2020_10_01\operations_activity_log_alerts_operations.py in create_or_update(self, resource_group_name, activity_log_alert_name, activity_log_alert_rule, **kwargs)
381             map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
382             error = self._deserialize.failsafe_deserialize(_models.ErrorResponse, pipeline_response)
--> 383             raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error, error_format=ARMErrorFormat)
384
385         if response.status_code == 200:

```
HttpResponseError: (AuthorizationFailed) The client '17abcd' with object id '17abcd' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/write' over scope '/subscriptions/59abcd/resourceGroups/MyResource/providers/Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/test' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
Code: AuthorizationFailed
Message: The client '17abcd'' with object id '17abcd'' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/write' over scope '/subscriptions/59abcd/resourceGroups/MyResource/providers/Microsoft.Insights/activityLogAlerts/test' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

Please help.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the below code with a Service Principal with an Owner or Contributor role at the Subscription level the code ran successfully like below:-

[image]

Service Principal role at the subscription level :-
[image]

[image]

Now, I tried creating the same Activity log with another Service Principal **without the Owner or contributor role** but just the reader role. It failed with the **same error code** as yours:-

Output failed:-

[image]

[image]

I added the same service principal with a **Contributor role scoped** at the **resource group level** and the error was resolved:-

[image]

[image]

Output ran successfully:-

[image]

**Make sure your app/service principal have at least Contributor or Owner role assigned at the Subscription or Resource Group Level in your Azure Subscription.**

Comment: Thank you so much, @SiddheshDesai!  This problem had bothered me for weeks, now you solved the mystery!  Very much appreciate it!!